# Android Java - Creating a Cronjob

Tags: java, android, cron

I want make a "Cronjob" that works in the backend and start all 30 Mins a methode. If the function return true (or someting else) the "Cronjob" create a Status-Bar-Notification.

Is that possible in Android?
And when yes, with which function?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Android [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) is the class you are looking for. It can trigger an intent to be sent to your application at set intervals so you can run any task you would like.