# Run code at specific time, every day

Tags: java, android

I want to disable service at [user choice] and enable it at [user choice] for every day. What is the best way to accomplish that?

Should i use Calendar? (Calculate start and end times, or something else? )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266878/android-regular-task-cronjob-equivalent

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Justin Breitfeller's answer to [Android Java - Creating a Cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605912/android-java-creating-a-cronjob):

> The Android [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) is the class you are looking for. It can
>   trigger an intent to be sent to your application at set intervals so
>   you can run any task you would like.

Answer (score 1):

What you looking for is called 'Cron'.
It can be achieved with the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).
`AlarmManager myAlarmManager = Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)`